# Restricting type parameters

Tags: c#, java, generics

In Java I can specify bounds on types passed into methods like this

```
public <C extends Command, CH extends CommandHandler<C>> void
   registerCommandHandler(Class<C> command, Class<CH> handler) {
   System.out.println("command class is " + command.getCanonicalName());
   Object instance = handler.newInstance();
   :
}
```

Where **Command** and **CommandHandler** is defined like this

```
class Command {}

abstract class CommandHandler<C extends Command> {
    public abstract void handle(C command);
}
```

This generic construction makes the Java compiler enforce that the command and command handler always matches each other. Thus the following example will compile just fine

```
registerCommandHandler(CreateCustomerCommand.class, CreateCustomerCommandHandler.class);
```

but this won't compile

```
registerCommandHandler(CreateCustomerCommand.class, DeleteCustomerCommandHandler.class);
```

Is it possible to create a similar type safe construction in C# where I on compile time can limit the scope of the types passed into a function ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public void registerCommandHandler<C, CH>(C command, CH handler)
            where C : Command
            where CH : CommandHandler<C>
        {
             // other C# code here
        }
```

After reading your comments, I think you want something like this:

```
public void registerCommandHandler<C, CH>()
        where C : new()
        where CH : new()
        where C : Command
        where CH : CommandHandler<C>
    {
        C instanceOfC = new C();
        CH instanceOfCH = new CH();
    }
```

Comment: Will that work ?. In the example above I am passing the type as a parameter not an object instance.

Comment: Then you dont need to define the parameters. Simply calling registerCommandHandler<Command,Handler>() would work.

Comment: assuming I call it with **registerCommandHandler<CustomerCommand, CustomerCommandHandler>()** how do I then access the generic parameters inside the function ?.

Comment: @Lars: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: in the java code above command and handler holds references to classes which I can then do stuff with such as make instances of them. If I call the C# method with no parameters how do I get hold on these ?

Comment: To call the C# registerCommandHandler method, try `registerCommandHandler<Command, CommandHandler<Command>>(new Command(), new CommandHandler<Command>());`

Comment: but that way I must call them with an instance and not a type. I want to be able to do **registerCommandHandler(CustomerCommand, CustomerCommandHandler)** precisely because I don't want to pass instances around.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit or define what should be allowed for type T, C or CH or whatever with 
`where T : SomeType`...

For example if you have those 2 interfaces (or abstract classes or whatever...)

```
    public interface ICommand
    {
    }
    public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
    {
    }
```

you can restrict that in your method that both parameters must match...

```
    public void registerCommandHandler<C, CH>(C command, CH handler)
        where C : ICommand
        where CH : ICommandHandler<C>
    {

    }
```

you don't have to define interfaces for that of cause, its just an example.